'more to the point'—means what, precisely?
Internet sources differ when it comes to the semantics of English 'more to the point'.
My question here:
Does it mean 'more precisely' or rather 'more importantly' or even 'additionally', essentially?
I can't believe it can mean both 'more importantly' and 'more precisely', because 'importance' and 'precision' are very different concepts.

"to the point" is an idiomatic expression, it means apt, pertinent, relevant.  In idioms, the words of the expression do not always make literal sense,  but are rather figurative.  One of the many meanings of the word "point" is topic, argument, idea - so you can see how "to the point" kind of makes sense.

I always use 'to the point' to mean 'relevant to the current discussion or topic'.

I have a difficult time imagining it being used to mean "more precisely." As Paul said, it means "more relevantly," which is sometimes more precise, and usually more important.

@AndyBonner - if you ask me to summarize the work I have done yesterday on a work project, and, part way through, I start to tell you about my cat's amusing antics with a ball of wool, or my blocked drain, you might well say 'Keep to the point!', 'Stick to the point!', 'Don't wander off the point', etc.

@MichaelHarvey I am struggling to understand how your comment is a reaction to Andy Bonner's comment.

@phoog - thank you for your comment. Not so much a reaction, as an addition, clarifying (I hope) Andy's correct assertion that 'more to the point' means 'more relevantly'. Clarifying and reinforcing by showing an example of not speaking to the point.

@MichaelHarvey (Something that I do often. It's often assumed that all comments are challenges, but I often give "amplifying" ones.)

Literally, it means "more directly relevant to the topic being discussed." But it is sometimes used with the meanings you suggest.
Nobody ever promised that languages are used "logically."

OK. From the comments above—and your answer here—I conclude 'more to the point' is  idiomatic adverb, typically meaning 'more relevantly'.

If 'more to the point' is idiom, then it may well have specific stress pattern (idiomatic melody). For example, intuition tells me to pronounce it 'more to the '. That correct?

Assuming 'point' represents 'topic' or 'matter' in the idiom 'more to the point', then I'm inclined to interpret 'more to the point' as 'more [statements, comments, data, substance…] to the point'. Thus I tend to interpret 'more' additively. But addition and relevance are different concepts. So, is it erroneous to interpret 'more' additively here?

For example, let the topic be the integer 3. Then '3 is an odd prime. More to the point [in addition, NOT more relevantly], it's the second triangular number.'. Note that, here, pronunciation would probably be ' to the point' rather than 'more to the '.

Secondary stress is on more, and primary stress is on point.

No, more here does not mean anything like here is further material that is relevant. What it means instead is The following material is of greater relevance than was the material just discussed.

OK. That's precise answer to my question. It triggers another question. Generally, can 'more' be used as synonym for 'further' or 'additional'? Because if true, than my idiolectic interpretation of 'more to the point' as given above isn't absurd.

Yes, absolutely. For example, To learn more synonyms, consult a dictionary or Would you care for more beans? The interpretation you asked about is not at all absurd. Merely incorrect here.

Let's try to rephrase 'additional/ further material pertaining to the topic' by using 'more' instead of 'additional'/ 'further' and 'point' instead of 'topic'. What would the result look like? 'more on the point'?

Consider Once I learned of Christopher Columbus’s mistreatment of the Native Americans, I went to the library to read more about his crimes.  Or, They suspect the fire was arson, but the police have released no more on that point.
